# How to divide a string with a regex through characters that are outside square brackets?

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
PARTNER6;PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5];PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]    -> ∞
```

I want to divide it like this:

```
PARTNER6

PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5]

PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]
```

I tried to use this expression, but it divides everything including what is in parentheses

```
[\s,;]+
```

I can't figure out how to divide only what is outside the brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex to get all of your matches:

```sh
\w+(?:\[[^]]*\]\w*)*\w*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKDPKs/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\w+`: Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:\[[^]]*\]\w*)*`: Match `[...]` string followed by 0 or more word characters. Repeat this group 0 or more times
- `\w*`: Match 0 or more word characters

**Code:**

```
jshell> String regex = "\\w+(?:\\[[^]]*\\]\\w*)*\\w*";
regex ==> "\\w+(?:\\[[^]]*\\]\\w*)*\\w*"

jshell> String string = "PARTNER6;PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5];PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]    -> ∞";
string ==> "PARTNER6;PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5];PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]    -> ∞"

jshell>  Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(string).results().map(MatchResult::group).collect(Collectors.toList());
$3 ==> [PARTNER6, PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5], PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a regex find all approach here:

```
String input = "PARTNER6;PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5];PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]";
String pattern = "(\\w+(?:\\[.*?\\])?);?";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This prints:

```
PARTNER6
PARTNER7[PORTAL4;PORTAL5]
PARTNER1[PARTNER1WEB]
```

The regex pattern used above matches a word with `\w+`, followed by an optional term in square brackets, followed by optional semicolon.